# Losing comments on superuser and meta with Safari on mac

Tags: support, safari

Ok, this has happened 3 times in a row now, and it's very annoying.

I'm using the most updated safari (4.0.5) and mac os x (10.6.3) and when I tried to add comments on superuser and now on meta I got a blank page with no back button. I type in my comment, press the "Add Comment" button and everything goes instantly blank - with no http activity what so ever. Like there was a javascript on that button that deleted everything on the page. I can still right click and see all the original source in there, but I can't do anything else - including recovering whatever I typed in the comment. I don't know how to reproduce this, how to debug it / see any logs on what really happened or why it happens.

And sometimes I even get logged out of the trilogy site I'm currently on, and have to login again! That happens mostly when I'm trying to cast votes, tho.

Usually when we lose a submit in Safari, we just hit back and the form will be there. Safari does have a good system to prevent losing data, but it's flawed as far as I see. If you quit safari next time you open it, you can "Reopen last closed session", or something like that. But if you quit BEFORE doing that, you lost that session for ever. And if you do recover the session the back and forth button history of each tab is already lost. Form recovery is very similar - it's one time only, and it's not very reliable, but it's fairly enough for most times.

Well, I got two questions here: **Is anyone else having that bug?**

And **how can I prevent from losing form data in Safari again?** (maybe this second one should go to superuser, tho I already have a [very similar unanswered question](https://superuser.com/questions/109681/lazarus-form-recovery-for-safari) there).

Or maybe, how should I be properly using Safari if I'm not using correctly?

Comment: Have you tried flushing the cache?

Comment: "Have you tried flushing the cache?" is the new "have you turned it off and on again?"

Comment: @json I've just started a fresh browser session but I haven't even considered flushing the cache. I still rather not try to blindly fix it, I'd like better to identify why it's happening.

Comment: well, it's simple: It seems like it's a localized problem, which implies that the problem is on your end, and not on SOFU. @Sathya http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gt9j80Jkc_A

Comment: Clear your cache like json suggested. If SOFU was updated and your cache still use the old version then problems like this occur. If you have log-on problems, clear your cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well, I got two questions here: Is
>   anyone else having that bug?

I'm running Safari on Mac. No, I'm not having this bug.

> And how can I prevent from losing form
>   data in Safari again? (maybe this
>   second one should go to superuser, tho
>   I already have a very similar
>   unanswered question there).

Clear your cache by going to Safari => Empty Cache => Empty. If you're still having problems, report back here.

Comment: I'll sure report back if anything happens... But, just to report something already, it still didn't happen since last time I reboot and thus restart Safari as well. No "Empty Cache" was done. But that wouldn't be the first time of any. And thanks for your confirmation report as well!

Answer (score 0):

Flushing the cache isn't a blind solution, it's often *the* solution to various browser rendering issues. If some javascript or stylesheet changes have been made on the site recently, then it's quite possible that the code being run on the client no longer matches the code on the server end that is receiving data.  Restarting your browser or at least flushing the cache for the relevant domain(s) should clear things up in almost all cases.

Comment: Well, as I've said, I tried restarting the browser already. Many times. If that flushes the cache, as I believe it does, what else could I do to flush it again?

Comment: @Cawas: That will usually not flush the cache. If you're using Safari,  click on the `Safari` menu (right next to File), then click Empty Cache.

Comment: @waiwai thanks for both infos - that's the last place I'd look for it. I should have used `Help` menu and typed `cache` tho. Sorry for acting newbish there.